# What's happening, when a red and a green (laser-) light meet red glass?

Tags: visible-light, vision

I would think, that the green light is blocked and the red light travels through the glass undisturbed. Therefore what you see is a red beam, but no green beam after the glass.

'Blocking the green light' means: the green light interacts with the electrons in the red glass, bringing them to a higher energy level, and than these electrons emit a all kinds of electromagnetic waves (heat, light...) in all directions (including a bit of green light too)

This is the reason, this red glass looks red in white light, because everything but red is blocked.

And this is the reason, every object has a red tint, when wearing red glasses. All you can see is the red potion of the reflected light from the object.

Is this correct?

Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Sounds about right. Colored glass or plastic "filters" absorb some wavelengths more strongly than others. The energy that the filter absorbs raises the temperature of the plastic or glass. They can be sneaky though! I have a pair of red safety glasses that generally make the world look deep red, but I still can see the light of a blue LED through them. The filter apparently has a "notch" in its absorption spectrum near the wavelength of the blue light. It must be a narrow notch, because if you held the glasses up to white light, you would say that they were pure, deep red.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!